# problem adding more than one recycle view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

hello hope you doing well !
I have problem hope find the solution with you

I have myadpter2 java

```
    package com.example.adopt_pet_app;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

public class myadapter2 extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Adopters,myadapter2.myviewholder>
{
  public myadapter2(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Adopters> options1) {
    super(options1);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Adopters model)
  {

   holder.adopname.setText(model.getAdoname());
    holder.adoptphone.setText(model.getAdophone());
    holder.adopemail.setText(model.getAdoemail());

  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
  {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow2,parent,false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
  }

  class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
  {

     TextView adopname,adoptphone,adopemail;
    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
      super(itemView);
      adopname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
      adoptphone=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.phonetext);
      adopemail=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);


    }
  }
}
```

and I want call it here ..

```
    package com.example.adopt_pet_app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Adopters_u_d extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recview2;
    myadapter myadapter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adopters_u_d);
        recview2=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recview2);
        recview2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Adopters> options1;
        options1 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Adopters>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Adopters"), Adopters.class)
                .build();

        myadapter2=new myadapter(options1);
        recview2.setAdapter(myadapter2);

    }
}
```

but it gave me error when i try call options1 it say this

[image]

its becouse i made one before for my pet page and now i want make another for my Adopter i dont want change petinfo becouse i need it its same code but with name options instated options1  please help thank you

Comment: Just change ```new myadapter``` to ```new myadapter2```

Comment: The adapter1 has the pets info, the adapter2 has the adopters. In the activity, myadapter2 is the second adapter being cast to the first adapter which is ```myadapter```

Comment: ohhhhhhh yes !! thank yoouuu !

Comment: Ok. For easier programming, consider naming the classes something comprehensible to you. So instead of myadapter, try ```PetsInfoAdapter``` and ```AdoptersAdapter``` etc.